# MT7601U Wireless Adapter not working on Linux 5.4.0

Tags: linux, wifi, drivers, usb-device

My problem is related to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1205254/ralink-tech-mt7601u-wireless-adapter-on-xubuntu), but the solution there provided did not work for me.

I bought this USB wireless adapter to use with my freshly installed Kubuntu-20.04, but when I try to connect to my wi-fi, the following notification appears after a few seconds of trying:

[image]

This is the `dmesg` relevant output:

```
[    7.572552] usbcore: registered new interface driver mt7601u
[    8.981461] fbcon: Taking over console
[    9.017252] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 200x56
[   10.014499] RTL8208 Fast Ethernet r8169-200:00: attached PHY driver [RTL8208 Fast Ethernet] (mii_bus:phy_addr=r8169-200:00, irq=IGNORE)
[   10.027583] random: crng init done
[   10.027585] random: 7 urandom warning(s) missed due to ratelimiting
[   10.357984] r8169 0000:02:00.0 ens133: Link is Down
[   10.440792] mt7601u 2-2:1.0 wlx20e3170d652f: renamed from wlan0
[   32.961568] wlx20e3170d652f: authenticate with 24:fd:0d:d6:88:05
[   32.980314] wlx20e3170d652f: send auth to 24:fd:0d:d6:88:05 (try 1/3)
[   33.183579] wlx20e3170d652f: send auth to 24:fd:0d:d6:88:05 (try 2/3)
[   33.387574] wlx20e3170d652f: send auth to 24:fd:0d:d6:88:05 (try 3/3)
[   33.591577] wlx20e3170d652f: authentication with 24:fd:0d:d6:88:05 timed out
[   87.518369] r8169 0000:02:00.0 ens133: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Half - flow control off
[   87.518383] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): ens133: link becomes ready
```

I would guess that the problem is due to the failed authentication attempts, but I don't know what to do about it.

`sudo lshw -C network` output:

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: ens133
       version: 05
       serial: 00:e0:4c:76:27:3d
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=half firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw ip=10.42.0.2 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:5 ioport:e800(size=256) memory:fafff000-faffffff memory:faff8000-faffbfff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@2:2
       logical name: wlx20e3170d652f
       serial: 20:e3:17:0d:65:2f
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=mt7601u driverversion=5.4.0-56-generic firmware=N/A link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

`lsusb` relevant output:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp. MT7601U Wireless Adapter
```

Thanks for helping.

**EDIT 1:** link to related question updated.

**EDIT 2:** new relevant information. The symptoms described above happen when I try to connect to my home wi-fi, but I just tried to connect to my phone internet (hotspot) and it worked. So maybe it is a router issue? Still have no idea how to solve it.

Comment: I haven't had much luck with the mt7601u driver.  In my case, I'm on Fedora 33 (kernel 5.9), and I see a similar problem as was reported in the other question you linked to.  When I use this driver (with a no-name "generic" USB WiFi adapter that uses this chip), it works ... for a while.  But eventually, my system hangs and I have to power-cycle it - nothing else works to get it back.  There are errors reported in the systemd journal about CPU hangs, with stack tracebacks that go through the mt7601u driver.  I ended up having to ditch this adapter and use a different one.  No problems since.

Comment: Well, since I got no answers, I ended up doing the same thing and buying another adapter (TL-WN722N). Works perfectly.